# Listing all files and folders recursively via terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a folder containing about 2000 sub-folders, some containing even more sub-folders and some with files. I've used this code via Terminal:

cd /path/to/folder

ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^/]*//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/'

to return a very nice recursive list of all the sub-folders but it does not list the files *within* those folders. Does anyone know how to amend this code so it produces the recursive folder list *and* includes the files?

For reasons that aren't worth getting into I'm limited to using Terminal on this computer and can't try a different method using C# or Java. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `find` like this:

```
find $PWD
```

Or using this alias:

```
alias stree='ls -R | grep : | sed -e '\''s/:$//'\'' -e '\''s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'\'' -e '\''s/^/ /'\'' -e '\''s/-/|/'\'''
```

Comment: Thank you, the find command was the first suggestion to return the file names, but is there any way to add the recursive structure (it's MUCH easier to work with)?